next-auth beta version Custom error handling not possible
I am using next-auth @beta for authentication. Signin and signout working properly. If any error occur like password mismatch or user not found, it is not throwing the error. instead response is getting as {error: 'CredentialsSignin', status: 200, ok: true, url: null}
if email same and password different it is literally logging in even though credential doesn't match.
// [...nextauth].js

import NextAuth, { AuthError } from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import Facebook from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { User } from "@/model/User";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    Google({
      profile(profile) {
        return { ...profile, role: profile.role ?? "user" };
      },
    }),
    Facebook({
      profile(profile) {
        return { ...profile, role: profile.role ?? "user" };
      },
    }),
    Credentials({
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        try {
          const user = await User(credentials.email);

          if (!user || !user.password) {
            console.log('No user found');
            throw new AuthError("User not found.")
          }

          const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compare(
            credentials.password,
            user.password
          );

          if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
            throw new AuthError("Incorrect password");
          }
      
          if (user.verified !== 1) {
            throw new AuthError("User not verified");
          }

          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error in authorization:', error);
          // throw error; // Re-throw the error
        }
      },
    }),
  ],

});


this is auth.js inside src folder
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGoogleReCaptcha } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";
import { faEye, faEyeSlash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import Link from "next/link";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, useSession, getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from "formik";
import { FormGroup, Label } from "reactstrap";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);
  const [passwordVisible, setPasswordVisible] = useState(false);
  const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha();

  const initialValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email").required("Required"),
    password: Yup.string().min(5, "Too Short!").required("Required"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("session", session);
    if (status === "authenticated" && session?.user?.type) {
      if (session.user.type === "STUDENT") {
        router.push(`/`);
      } else if (
        session.user.type === "CONSULTANCIES" ||
        session.user.type === "SUPER_ADMIN"
      ) {
        if (session.user.is_approved === 1) {
          router.push("/admin/dashboard");
        }
      }
    }
  }, [session, status, router]);

  const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);

    try {
      const signInResponse = await signIn("credentials", {
        ...values,
        redirect: false,
      });
      console.log("signInResponse", signInResponse);
      if (!signInResponse.error) {
        toast.success("Login Successful");

        // Fetch the updated session
        const updatedSession = await getSession();

        if (updatedSession && updatedSession.user) {
          if (updatedSession.user.type === "STUDENT") {
            router.push(`/`);
          } else if (
            updatedSession.user.type === "CONSULTANCIES" ||
            updatedSession.user.type === "SUPER_ADMIN"
          ) {
            if (updatedSession.user.is_approved === 1) {
              router.push("/admin/dashboard");
            }
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error("Session is not defined");
        }

        setIsSubmitting(false);
      } else {
        throw new Error("Login failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof AuthError) {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      } else {
        console.error("Login error", error);
      }
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible);
  };

  if (!isMounted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      className="mt-5"
    >
      <Form>
        <h4 className="text-center">
          <b>Login</b>
        </h4>
        <p className="text-muted lh-large">
          Access personalized support and services for your study abroad journey
        </p>

        {errorMessage && <h1 className="z-1">{errorMessage}</h1>}

        <FormGroup>
          <Label>Email *</Label>
          <Field type="text" id="email" name="email" className="form-control" />
          <ErrorMessage name="email" component="div" className="text-danger" />
        </FormGroup>

        <FormGroup>
          <Label>Password *</Label>
          <div className="input-group">
            <Field
              type={passwordVisible ? "text" : "password"}
              id="password"
              name="password"
              className="form-control"
            />
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn border"
              onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
            >
              {passwordVisible ? (
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEyeSlash} />
              ) : (
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye} />
              )}
            </button>
          </div>
          <ErrorMessage
            name="password"
            component="div"
            className="text-danger"
          />
        </FormGroup>

        <div className="pt-1 mb-2">
          <div className="d-grid gap-2 d-flex justify-content-between mb-2">
            <a className="small text-muted" href="/forgot-password">
              Forgot password?
            </a>
            <button
              className="btn btn-block login-btn"
              type="submit"
              disabled={isSubmitting}
            >
              {isSubmitting ? "Logging in..." : "Login"}
            </button>
          </div>

          <div className="login-social-title">
            <h5>Sign in with</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between gap-2 mt-2">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-google"
              onClick={() => signIn("google")}
            >
              Google
            </button>

            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-facebook"
              onClick={() => signIn("facebook")}
            >
              Facebook
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <p className="my-1 lh-lg">
          Don't have an account? <Link href={"/register"}>Register here</Link>
        </p>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;

this is login page. Error is correctly getting is auth.js but not as response in login page.
